# Copy pasting a microsoft word file into another folder with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've recently started experimenting with vba to automate some of my daily tasks in Microsoft Word. I am working on a code that will allow the user to select a destination folder and also the files (.doc) to be copied into the selected destination folder.

The following code runs with no errors, however the files do not get copy pasted into the destination folder.

I will greatly appreciate any help to resolve this minute issue.

Regards,

Derek

```
Sub copydocs()

Dim items As Long
Dim file_path As Variant
Dim folder_path As Variant

    'Ask user for input'

    items = InputBox("Give me some input")


    'Select Destination Folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        folder_path = .SelectedItems(1)
        .Show
    End With


    ' Open the file dialog
    For i = 1 To items
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
            .AllowMultiSelect = True
            .Show
            file_path = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With

        ' Copy paste       
        Dim fs As Object
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        fs.CopyFile file_path, folder_path
        Set fs = Nothing

    Next i    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues.

The variable i isn't declared anywhere.

You are attempting to save the folder path before the dialogue has returned it.

```
Sub copydocs()
    Dim i As Integer                ' CHANGE: New declare.
    Dim fs As Object                ' CHANGE: Moved to top.
    Dim items As Long
    Dim file_path As Variant
    Dim folder_path As Variant

    'Ask user for input.
    items = InputBox("Give me some input")

    'Select Destination Folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        ' CHANGE: Switched order of next two lines.
        .Show
        folder_path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    ' Open the file dialog
    For i = 1 To items
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
            .AllowMultiSelect = True
            .Show
            file_path = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With

        ' Copy paste
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        fs.CopyFile file_path, folder_path
        Set fs = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```